# mod_rewrite rule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What rule translates urls like so?

`host.com/plastic_toys/pink_barbie/`
`host.com/index.php?q=plastic+toys+pink+barbie`

The number of components in the category and product name vary.

Edit:

I guess this rule does part of the job:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?q=$1+$2 [L]
```

The problem with the above rule is that it does not take care of converting underscores to `+`, so it translates like this:

`host.com/plastic_toys/pink_barbie/`
`host.com/index.php?q=plastic_toys+pink_barbie`

I guess I have to delegate that conversion to PHP. Now is there a way to test if the rule actually does the conversion the way I imagine it would?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First - I would suggest using the following rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_]+)/([a-zA-Z_]+)/?$ /index.php?q1=$1&q2=$2 [L,QSA]
```

The RewriteCond each check that a valid file or directory does not exist (for instance if you want to have a static /help.html and it exists, or /FAQ/index.php and it exists then the RewriteRule will not fire.

I've split out the parameters into 2 items - so you can treat them as separate parameters (if you want to treat it as 1 parameter just change it to /index.php?q=$1-$2 or some other separator that you want - I would say do not use + since you want to parse off that character anyway).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of the conditions. I ended up using the two lines you suggested with `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?q=$1+$2 [L]` as the rule and it works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Is there a reason (existing code, etc) that you need to do this totally as a rewrite?

Normally, I do

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

and then parse `$_GET["q"]` or even just parse `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` directly.  `preg_match()` is your friend here.

It takes way less time to use one of these two methods than it does trying to come up with a weird rewrite.

Comment: Thank you MPD, unfortunately I find both rewrite rules and regex utterly confusing. For instance I do not understand what you are doing with those three lines. I edited my question - could you confirm that I'd get what I expect with the rule I have included last?

Comment: @sobedai pretty much summed it up.  The difference is that my rules redirect all files/directories not found to index.php, and PHP is responsible for parsing out the parameters into parts.  This is essentially the way Wordpress, Drupal, and other frameworks handle pretty URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing.  How would a rule know where to draw the line between a category and product.  What if the query had 3 parameters.  Are the first two the category and the last the product or is the first the category and the last two the product.

Comment: No need to distinguish products and categories, because both end up as values to `q` parameter.